# how to select latest record from a created column

Tags: oracle

I have a table that has a bunch of records that are updated frequently, and I am trying to write a code to pull only the latest record. In an ideal situation, I would use the updated_date column to pull the latest record, however, in many situations, the updated-date column is blank and so, I have to create a new column using the following code:

```
CASE WHEN UPDATED_DATE IS NULL THEN CREATED_DATE ELSE UPDATED_DATE END latest_date
```

Basically I made a new column for when updated_date is blank, use the created_date and now, my data looks like this:

| updated_date | audit_id | created_date | latest_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-02 | 006 | 2018-06-06 | 2021-04-02 |
| NULL | 006 | 2018-06-06 | 2018-06-06 |
| 2020-03-01 | 006 | 2018-06-06 | 2020-03-01 |
| NULL | 007 | 2018-07-07 | 2018-07-07 |
| 2020-04-01 | 007 | 2018-07-07 | 2020-04-01 |
| 2019-09-08 | 007 | 2018-07-07 | 2019-09-08 |

What I would like to retrieve is the latest info only:

| updated_date | audit_id | created_date | latest_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-02 | 006 | 2018-06-06 | 2021-04-02 |
| 2020-04-01 | 007 | 2018-07-07 | 2020-04-01 |

If someone could please let me know how this data can be retried, that would be great.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your intention is to get the most recent row for each `audit_id`.  If so, you can do something like

```
select *
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by audit_id
                                      order by coalesce( updated_date, created_date ) desc ) rn
          from your_table t)
 where rn = 1;
```

If you can have two rows with the same `audit_id` and `latest_date`, you could use the `rank` or `dense_rank` function rather than `row_number` to handle ties differently but I'm guessing that is not an issue you'll need to deal with and arbitrarily breaking the tie with `row_number` is sufficient.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Just wondering if you could explain 'coalesce'  and 'over partition by', I am new to oracle/sql so not sure what those functions are. Also, I searched 'coalesce' online and it says that this function returns the first non-NULL value. What I am looking for is not the first non-NULL value but the LATEST non-NULL value. Thank you

Comment: @ops_mltsd - `coalesce` returns the first non-null value of the parameters passed in.  It's equivalent logically to your `case` statement, just more compact.  The `row_number` analytic function takes all the rows for a particular `audit_id` (what you're partitioning by), orders by the equivalent of your `latest_date`, and assigns a row number.   So each `audit_id` will have a `rn` of 1, 2, 3, etc. depending on the number of rows in the table.  Then the outer subquery takes all the `rn=1` rows which gives you just the most recent row for each `audit_id`.

Comment: thanks for explaining it so well, there are some instances in my data where all the UPDATED_DATE is NULL, in that case, I have to take the latest CREATED_DATE. I am guessing this coalesce and rn=1 function searches both the updated_date and created_date and takes the latest non-NULL date?

Comment: @ops_mltsd - Right.  That's the point of the `coalesce`.  You could replace the `coalesce` with the `case` statement you had for `latest_date`.  `coalesce` is just more compact.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COALESCE` and  `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` (Oracle 12):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY COALESCE(UPDATED_DATE, CREATED_DATE) DESC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: thank you, what is the difference between FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY and row_number?